# Programatically auto layout is working in Xcode 6.4 but not with Xcode 7.1 beta

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I have added view programatically and give it constraint. Which is working perfectly fine with Xcode 6.4 and iOS 8. But when I try to run same thing with Xcode 7.1 beta, my app is crashing without giving any error. My code is given below:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:IBviewContainer
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:0
                                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:leftConstraint];
```

I don't know what is missing. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: nothing, my app is just crashing, if I comment this lines my app is running perfectly fine

Comment: does it work in 7.0 ? non-beta ?

Comment: not checked that, as I don't have that Xcode

Comment: can you try changing NSLayoutAttributeLeft with NSLayoutAttributeLeading for self.view too ?

Comment: What is the crash log ? is it running fine in XCode 7 ?

Comment: @ogres great man, It worked .. Thanks you saved my time.. Its worked but don't know why NSLayoutAttributeLeft was not working. Do you have any clue for that?

Comment: left is considered as leading and right is considered as trailing!!! you should use leading and trailing instead of right and left constraints

Comment: glad it helped :) probably the internal structure was changed and it worked "by magic" in old version :)